# mysql sort data result A-Z and split each section with lines

Tags: php, mysql

I have few thousands of rows in a mysql table
after selecting the records in ascending order i want to format each section of the results in alphabetic order in this format

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
-------------------------------------
b
bab
babc
babcd
babcdef
-------------------------------------
c
ca
cab
cabc
cabcd
cabcde
cabcdef
-------------------------------------
```

I need to do is to demacate each of the sections of the alphabet with lines.

Comment: While looping over your result, check if the first letter of the current record is the same as the first letter of the previous record – if not, output the line.

Comment: @CBroe How will i check the previous  record from a while looop?

Comment: @CBroe I finally got it to work by setting the the ascii character for "A" before beginning the while loop for the result, in the while loop, i check for the first letter of the string if it matches the ascii character, if not i draw a line and increment the ascii code by 1 to represent the next letter.. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php (and most other languages) all strings are infact arrays of characters. So $string[0] will hold the first character of the string.

```
<?php
$rows = get_rows_from_mysql();

$section = false;

foreach ($rows as $row) {

  if ($section != strtolower($row['name'][0])) {
    if ($section != false) echo "------------------------";
    $section = strtolower($row['name'][0]);
  }

  echo $section['name'];
}
?>
```

Above code would not handle grouping of numbers or special characters like !"#, but you should get the point.

Comment: I finally got it to work by setting the the ascii character for "A" before beginning the while loop for the result, in the while loop, i check for the first letter of the string if it matches the ascii character, if not i draw a line and increment the ascii code by 1 to represent the next letter.. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

I would have created a variable with the initial value of *a*. Once it for the first time hits a record with the first letter *a* - set the variable to *b* and print a line. Once the first letter is *b* - set the variable to *c* and print a line.

Hope you understand what I mean.

Good luck!

Comment: pls can you explain this better to me?